# I have one dropdown which is an array, and i have a button that will produce the same dropdown

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have one dropdown which is an array and i have a button that will reproduce the same dropdown.

```
                    <select name="additional_prop_type[]" id="additional_prop_type" class="additional_prop_type">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
```

How can i get the value from the dropdown array(which is the same name) using jquery? My jquery code is something like this but only the first instance of the dropdown is working.

```
$(".additional_prop_type").each(function () {
    $(this).on("change", function(event){
        if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){
            alert($(this).val());
            //$(this).closest("div").find('.additionalAPC').css("display", "block");
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 'No'){
            alert($(this).val());
            //$(this).closest("div").find('.additionalAPC').css("display", "none");
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Can you further explain "a button that will reproduce the same dropdown"? Are you trying to capture the change events on a select element that you created dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need that within an each statement. The problem is that you're dynamically adding content that does not have the event listeners applied to them. You need to apply them to the document, or some other non dynamic parent that exists within the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) on page load. Anything added to the DOM after page load will not have events applied to the element.

```
    $(document).on('change', '.additional_prop_type', function(event){
        // Your Code Here
    });
```

I've added a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8xtgf304/1/) to show.

If you look in the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method's documentation you will see that the second argument passed is a [selector]. So your initial selector that you are applying the event to would be `$(document)`, but the second argument [selector] would be the actual dynamic element that you want the event to be applied to.

Comment: Sure! Don't forget to mark as the answer if this helped resolve your issue.